# Can anybody explain me why popToViewController: method doesn't work?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I use this code:

```
    MainViewController *mvc = [[MainViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController popToViewController:mvc animated:YES];
```

and it crash and I don't know why or where I am wrong. The error is:
 reason: 'Tried to pop to a view controller that doesn't exist.' , but my view controller exists.

If somebody can help me..

Comment: The error is telling you that your MainViewController instance does not exist in the navigationController stack.  When you pop to a certain view controller, that view controller has to exist in the navigation controller's stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend writing a method similar to this in the view controller you are popping.

```
- (void) popCurrentViewController
{
    UIViewController *popDestination = nil;
    for (UIViewController *viewController in self.navigationController.viewControllers)
    {
        if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[MainViewController class]])
        {
            popDestination = viewController;
        }
    }

    if (popDestination)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@ Popping...", self);
        [self.navigationController popToViewController:popDestination animated:true];
    }
    else
    {
        // Handle if it can not find the specific view controller.
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's a good code, it's what the @Steve said. I made something similar but thanks :)